# apache mina sftp client event listener for file download

Tags: apache-mina

Trying to implement an apache mina sshd sftp client. I would want to continuously intimate on the client end how much file size was uploaded/downloaded. Are there any event listeners for this?
I could see some SftpEventListener on the server side. Looking for something on the client.

In jscape library they have SftpProgressEvent which helps in getting this, looking for some similar functionality.